# Copy elision and move constructor

Tags: c++11, move, copy-elision

Consider the following definition of `Person`:

```
struct Person
{
    Person() { std::cout << "construct, "; }
    Person(const Person&) { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
    Person(Person&&) { std::cout << "move\n"; }
};
```

And 3 different functions to create a `Person`:

```
Person create1()
{
    std::cout << "create1: ";
    Person p1{};
    return p1;
}

Person create2()
{
    std::cout << "create2: ";
    if constexpr (true)
    {
        Person p1{};
        return p1;
    }
    else
    {
        Person p2{};
        return p2;
    }
}
    
Person create3()
{
    std::cout << "create3: ";
    if constexpr (true)
    {
        return Person{};
    }
    else
    {
        return Person{};
    }
}
```

Finally, I call the create functions as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Person p1 = create1();
    Person p2 = create2();
    Person p3 = create3();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
create1: construct
create2: construct, move
create3: construct
```

What bothers me is the output of `create2`. If in `create1` and `create3`, the move constructor is not called, why is it called in `create2`?

I am using GCC 12.0.0.

EDIT: Clang 13.0.0 does not call the move constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is an instance of NRVO in constant expression and [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> In constant expression and constant initialization, return value optimization (RVO) is guaranteed, however, named return value optimization (NRVO) is forbidden:

This is related to [CWG 2278](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2278).

EDIT

I reconsidered :-) It is called from `main()`, so it can't be constant initialization. With actual constant initialization neither gcc nor clang do NRVO. In this example ([see godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bqv6o8s35)):

```cpp
struct Person {
    bool was_moved;
    constexpr Person() : was_moved{false} { }
    constexpr Person(const Person&) : was_moved{false} { }
    constexpr Person(Person&&) : was_moved{true} { }
};
constexpr Person create() {
    if (true) {
        Person p1;
        return p1;
    }
    else {
        Person p2;
        return p2;
    }
}
constexpr Person p = create();

int main() {
    return p.was_moved;
}
```

`p.was_moved` is 1.

As to why gcc doesn't do NRVO in `create2()`, one answer could be that it is not mandatory, as per the cppreference link earlier. Another could be that gcc implementation of NRVO is very "fragile". For example it works when only one named variable is involved:

```cpp
Person create4() {
    Person p{};
    if  (true) {
        return p;
    }
    else {
        return p;
    }
}
```

but stops working when this whole thing is put in a sub-scope:

```cpp
Person create5() {
  {
    Person p{};
    if  (true) {
        return p;
    }
    else {
        return p;
    }
  }
}
```

([see godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YdTo9eM4s))

There is gcc bug from 2012 regarding both those issues: [Bug 53637 - NRVO not applied where there are two different variables involved](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53637) .

Comment: But with Clang it doesn't call the move constructor. Also, I would expect it to work without the constexpr.

Comment: What does this mean? "It is called from main(), so it can't be constant initialization."

Comment: I'm not sure (N)RVO at compile time makes sense...
The sub-scope is funny, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Constant initialization ([see cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization)) applies only to static and thread-local objects (plus some additional conditions). In these examples `create()` is called from `main()` and it initializes local variables, so it can't be constant initialization.

Comment: Well, RVO at compile time is mandatory (while NRVO is forbidden), so I assume it makes some sense. See https://godbolt.org/z/r44v58qb5